# Prove that $\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = a \implies \lim_{n \to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n} = a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-limit-theorems, proof-verification

Given a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\forall n: x_n > 0$, prove that

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = a \implies \lim_{n \to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n} = a.$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this proof is, that for $n$ sufficiently large, given that the ratio of consequent terms of the sequence is very close to $a$, we get $x_{n+1} = ax_n$, that is $x_n = a^n$. Then $\sqrt[n]{x_n} = \sqrt[n]{a^n} = a$.

**Proof.** Let $\epsilon > 0$. There is $n_0$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ we have

$$a - \epsilon < \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < a + \epsilon.$$

We can find bounds for $a_n$:

$$a_{n_0}(a - \epsilon)^{n - n_0} \le a_n \le a_{n_0}(a + \epsilon)^{n-n_0}.$$

Taking roots, we obtain

$$
\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0}(a - \epsilon)^{n - n_0}} \le
\sqrt[n]{a_n \vphantom{()^n} } \le
\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0}(a + \epsilon)^{n-n_0}},
$$
that is
$$
\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0} \vphantom{()^n} }{\sqrt[n]{(a - \epsilon)^{n}}}\sqrt[n]{(a - \epsilon)^{-n_0}} \le \sqrt[n]{a_n \vphantom{()^n} } \le
\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0} \vphantom{()^n} }{\sqrt[n]{(a + \epsilon)^{n}}}\sqrt[n]{(a + \epsilon)^{-n_0}}.
$$

Now we have that

$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} {\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0} \vphantom{()^n} }{\sqrt[n]{(a - \epsilon)^{n}}}\sqrt[n]{(a - \epsilon)^{-n_0}}} = a - \epsilon
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} {\sqrt[n]{a_{n_0} \vphantom{()^n} }{\sqrt[n]{(a + \epsilon)^{n}}}\sqrt[n]{(a + \epsilon)^{-n_0}}} = a + \epsilon.
$$

As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we get that the desired limit exists and $\lim_{n \to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n} = a$.

---

Is my proof correct? I would like to get any feedback.

Comment: If anybody knows how to make all `\sqrt` the same size, please do.

Comment: You could try inserting `\vphantom{()^n}` in the body of the roots that you deem too small. And I think your proof looks fine.

Comment: Thank you, @HaraldHanche-Olsen, that worked!

Comment: @ Cepelik You should consider three distinct cases seperately for a complete proof. 1. a=0, 2. 0 < a < \infty 3. a = \infty. 2nd case can also be shown using Cauchy's first theorem on limit.

Comment: You need "$x_n$'s", etc., throughout the main body, not "$a_n$'s"